# Does mySQL use index on delete?

Tags: mysql, innodb

I have a simple query :

```
delete from myTable where myDateTime < '2018-11-30 08:58:25.435140'
```

An `explain` shows me that it does not use myDateTime's index.

(it does when I change it for a `select`).

Do you have any clue?

It's a InnoDb table.

Comment: show the `explain` for the delete and select queries and  `show create table myTable` output.

Comment: Short answer: indexes can be igoned by MySQL.. Having a index does to mean MySQL is forced to use it.. a Index causes random disk i/o which can take up around 4-8 ms meaning it would be more "expensive" to index lookup search vs a one time random disk i/o (FULL table scan) when for example 70% of the table is matching the where filter..

Comment: A typical breakeven point:  If more than 20% of the table will be touched, the index is not used.  ("20" varies with the query, and the Optimizer does not always "do the better thing".)

Comment: I agree. Try experimenting with earlier date values, I think if you go back far enough, to the point where the condition matches less than 20% of the table (approximately), it'll magically start using the index.

Comment: Ok thanks! I didn't know that.